something in database is causing me to not be able to log into network admin of multisite
I'm updating my local development environment with a backup of the files and database from our hosting provider, and while I can log into each of the sub-sites in the multisite, I can't log into the network admin.  However, if I change the wp_config file to use the old database I was using before updating things, I can log in.
So that tells me that it's something in the database that is preventing it (not the code).
I've verified that the values in the wp_blogs table, and the wp_options for 'home' and 'siteurl' are the same.  I've also compared the user_meta capabilities and user_level, but they're the same.
I can log into the production environment that I created the backup from.
I'm not seeing any errors in the logs.  Any ideas of what could be different in the database that is preventing me from being able to log into the main site (network admin)?

There should be no issues entering the network admin if you're already logged in to a site on the network if that user is a super admin. Given that it's a local copy why not create a user to login with?

That was a good suggestion, Tom, but after creating a new user and making it a super-admin, I can only log into the sub-sites, not the main one.

The issue was there was another entry in the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory that was conflicting with the desired configuration.  I appreciate the help that was provided here.  Sorry for the wild goose chase!
